# When I add two number its giving me Sum is _G4080-_G4081 in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am summing two numbers in the code below, but the result is not what I expected, really . I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
me(a).

run:-
   write('Enter the first number: '),
   read(X),
   write('Enter the second Number: '),
   read(Y),nl,
   write('What would you like to do?'),nl,
   write('\na.Add.\n'),
   write('b.Subtract.\n'),
   write('c.Multiply.\n'),
   write('d.Divided.\n'),
   write('e.Exit'),nl,nl,
   write('Answer a, b, c, d or e:  '),
   read(C),
   check(C).

check(C):-me(C),S=X+Y,write('Sum is '),write(S),nl.
check(_):-me(C),write('Name not none'),nl.
```

Result giving :   it also giving me singletone variable error

14 ?- run.
        Enter the first number: 2.
        Enter the second Number: 3.

```
   What would you like to do?

   a.Add.
   b.Subtract.
   c.Multiply.
   d.Divided.
   e.Exit

   Answer a, b, c, d or e:  a.
   Sum is _G5053+_G5054
   true
```

What can I do ?

Comment: You'd have to use `(is)/2` to get arithmetic evaluation instead of `(=)/2` (unification). For example: `S is X + Y`

Comment: I have been used also this, But same thing happen , thank you for your comments

Comment: are you sure you've reloaded your program after having modified it? It's very unlikely that the same thing happened

Comment: Now it should actually tell you that the `is` arguments aren't sufficiently instanciated

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Prolog aren't universal. That means that the values you had in the rule `run`, for the variables `X` and `Y`, will be 'deleted' when this rule comes to an end.

So after

```
read(C),
   check(C).
```

There won't be any more values in the variables.

If you try something like

```
me(a).

   run:-write('Enter the first number: '),
   read(X),nl,
   write('Enter the second Number: '),
   read(Y),nl,
   write('What would you like to do?'),nl,
   write('\na.Add.\n'), 
   write('b.Subtract.\n'),
   write('c.Multiply.\n'),
   write('d.Divided.\n'),
   write('e.Exit'),nl,nl,
   write('Answer a, b, c, d or e:  '),
   read(C),
  me(C),S is X + Y, write('Sum is '),write(S),nl.
```

The results will be:

```
7 ?- run.
Enter the first number: 1.

Enter the second Number: 3.

What would you like to do?

a.Add.
b.Subtract.
c.Multiply.
d.Divided.
e.Exit

Answer a, b, c, d or e:  a.
Sum is 4
true.
```

or

```
8 ?- run.
Enter the first number: 21312.

Enter the second Number: 
|: 123.

What would you like to do?

a.Add.
b.Subtract.
c.Multiply.
d.Divided.
e.Exit

Answer a, b, c, d or e:  a.
Sum is 21435
true.
```

Just like you wanted.

So you have to find a way to do all the calculations in *one* rule.

Also, keep in mind that `=` in Prolog isn't the same like the other languages. In Prolog, `=` is used to check if two 'things' are the same. This means that this query:

```
3 = 3.
```

would return `true.`, the query `3=4.` would return `false.` etc.

So, since your query was `S=X+Y.`, Prolog tried to check

> If the value of S equals the sum of the values of X and Y.

and the result would be true or false.

The way to do arithmetic equations in Prolog is to use `is`.

> Result giving : it also giving me singletone variable error

This isn't an error, it's a warning. Singletone variables are variables that are declared but are never used. Your program can run fine when you have those warnings, but if you want to get rid of them, you can replace them with an underscore (`_`)

Comment: This is the right idea, but more accurately, you would say that, *variables introduced in the head or body of a given predicate clause are limited in scope to that clause*. In the case of the OP's predicate, the variables `X` and `Y` introduced in the predicate `run` are still exist when `check` is called and are still around when it returns, but they become out of scope when `check` is called, and the `X` and `Y` introduced in `check` are not the same `X` and `Y`.